# Создать простой сплайн

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, scipy

Как  сделать апроксимизацию сплайном в 1-2 строки кода и очень по простому?

Допустим данные датафрейм, хотя можно и для списка - не так важно.

```
    function
1   240.9
2   241.18
3   241.166
4   241.2
5   241.47
6   241.165
7   241.3
8   241.38
9   241.255
10  241.17
11  241.1
12  241.1
13  241.17
14  240.95
15  240.48
16  240.69
...
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот вам простой вариант из [документации](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation):

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)
y = np.exp(-x**2) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(50)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', ms=5)

spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y)
xs = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000)
plt.plot(xs, spl(xs), 'g', lw=3)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фактически тут к сплайну относится три строки, остальное подготовка данных и отрисовка:

```
# подключение библиотеки
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

# "тренировка" сплайна на известных данных
spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y)

# вычисление точек, которые вы хотите аппроксимировать 
spl(xs)
```

Вот конкретно под ваши данные код:

```
s = '''
1   240.9
2   241.18
3   241.166
4   241.2
5   241.47
6   241.165
7   241.3
8   241.38
9   241.255
10  241.17
11  241.1
12  241.1
13  241.17
14  240.95
15  240.48
16  240.69
'''.split('\n')

x = []
y = []
for t in s:
    if t:
        a,b = t.split()
        x.append(float(a))
        y.append(float(b))

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro') #, ms=5)

spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y)
xs = np.arange(1, 16, 0.5)
plt.plot(xs, spl(xs), 'g', lw=3)
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Анжелика Добавил прямо по вашим данным аппроксимацию